# Dependency tree for ActiveRecord ("what would be deleted if i delete a record")

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to build a flexible way of building a dependency tree for ActiveRecord.
The first Version already worked nicely but needed additional methods in all model classes to collect the sub-queries.
Now its time to do that automatically. I already have a working version for plain *has_many* queries that works perfectly.
Before i break my head over adding the additional cases i would like to know if i'm going in the right direction. Maybe i was just missing a already existing solution.

Here is my code:

```
# dropped into config/initializers/active_record.rb for quick testing

class ActiveRecord::Base

  class << self

    def dependency_tree(query = nil)
      query ||= self
      tree = {}

      own_ids_sql =  Arel.sql(self.select('id').to_sql)

      reflect_on_all_associations.collect do |relationship|
        if relationship.options[:dependent] == :destroy
          if relationship.inverse_of
            # normal has many

            base        = relationship.inverse_of.active_record
            foreign_key = base.connection.quote_column_name(relationship.inverse_of.association_foreign_key)
            table_name  = base.quoted_table_name
            condition   = "#{table_name}.#{foreign_key} IN (#{own_ids_sql})"

            tree[relationship.name] = {
              count: base.where(condition).count,
              sub: base.where(condition).dependency_tree
            }

          else
            # TODO : figure out the rest
            #        without auto inverse, like polymorphic
            #        maybe STI too? manual conditions on relation?

          end
        end
      end

      tree
    end

  end

  def dependency_tree
    self.class.dependency_tree(self.class.where(id: id))
  end

end
```

It builds recursive sub-queries always including the previous condition for the next level. At the moment it's only counting over dependent=destroy.

With the sub-queries instead of any actual objects get fast queries in database even for thousands of items and there is no need to load any actual data if it is not needed.
In my test-project i can easily build a tree with the above code for 100k+ items nested 4 levels deep.

Thoughts, ideas, suggestions?

Comment: this is a great idea